# React error when trying to pull multiple items from Firestore database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, list, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a React application that connects to Firebase's Firestore to store and retrieve some data.

This is how I try to pull the information:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { db } from "../config/firebase";
import { getDocs, collection } from "firebase/firestore";

export default function Bookings() {
    const [bookingsList, setBookingsList] = useState([]);

    const bookingsCollection = collection(db, "bookings");

    useEffect(() => {
        const getBookingsList = async() => {
            try {
                const data = await getDocs(bookingsCollection);
                const filteredData = data.docs.map((doc) => ({
                    ...doc.data(), 
                    id: doc.id
                }));
                setBookingsList(filteredData);
            } catch(e) {
                console.error("Error with fetching the bookings: " + e);
            }
        };
        getBookingsList();
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Bookings page</h1>
            {bookingsList.map((booking) => (
                <div>
                    <h4>Listing: {booking.listing}</h4>
                    <h4>Check In: {booking.check_in}</h4>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

It works when I just try to pull one piece of information: `<h4>Listing: {booking.listing}</h4>` for example. However when I try to pull multiple pieces of information as shown above: `<h4>Listing: {booking.listing}</h4><h4>Check In: {booking.check_in}</h4>` I get this error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {seconds, nanoseconds}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I have tried to figure this out to the best of my ability but my knowledge with React is quite limited at the moment so I have been unsuccessful. From looking online I found that in these situations we need to use the 'map()' method and I've seen it work for others, but I can't quite understand why it's not working for me.

Comment: What is the type of the data stored in `booking.check_in`?

Comment: Ah damn, I feel like an idiot now... It's a timestamp... Any idea for how I can display this in HTML form? I'd imagine I'd need to do some sort of conversion with date formatting?

Comment: What kind of timestamp is it?

Comment: It's a timestamp from google firebase's firestore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention, `check_in` is a [firebase timestamp object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp), looking at the docs for that there is a method available on that object that will convert it to a JS `Date` object. There are many ways you could then convert that to a string to make it a valid React child.

[MDN docs on the `Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) may be a start, but feel free to do your own googling.

At bare minimum, `booking.check_in.toDate()` should work for you.

Comment: It seems `booking.check_in.toDate()` doesn't work but i will find a way to convert it. Thank you for your help in diagnosing this error!

Comment: Ah if it doesn't automatically convert to a string then a quick fix might be to `...toDate().toString()`

Comment: Awesome, it works now without error. I just need to format it better. Thank you for your quick help!